# how to apply 3d effect in telerik bar chart in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-8, telerik, bar-chart

Anybody please help me to create a chart like

[image]

I have telerik control and already developed bar chart with 2D effect  but i dont know how to apply 3D effect?

Comment: I'll recommend you ask in the Telerik forums at http://www.telerik.com/community/forums.aspx

Comment: @ClausJørgensen:I asked to telerik but they are not provided 3D graph

Comment: Can any know how can i draw 3d graph my self like telrik